# replacing bootstrap toggle when clicked

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap navigation (fixed) in my website. I want to keep the mobile toggle viewable all the time, on all screen sizes. But when I click it (it opens up underneath) I want it to drop down from the top and 'replace' the toggle

I'm looking to see if this is possible, and or a good resource/reference to do this